# How do you call SetICMMode() for Color Management from python win32

Tags: pywin32

I'm writing a Python program that uses win32ui, win32print, win32con, etc.
My RGB(0,128,0) which looks like a nice Green on the Display, but is Olive-Yellow on the printer,

when I print like this:

```
    self.hDC.StartDoc ('doc title') # hDC is the Printer context for default printer
    self.hDC.StartPage ()
    # supposed to call wingdi.SetICMMode(hDc, ICM_ON) here
    dib = ImageWin.Dib (image) # A Python Pillow image
    dib.expose(self.hDC.GetHandleAttrib())
    self.hDC.EndPage ()
    self.hDC.EndDoc ()
```

But if I save 'image' from Pillow as a image.pdf and print from Adobe, the Green looks correct.
Microsoft Image Color Management (ICM) is suppose to help the Display and Printer colors match.
The SetICMMode(hDc, ICM_ON) function to help fix the Display vs Printer color difference is described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-seticmmode
And additional GDI functions in the basic ICM set are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wcs/basic-functions-for-use-within-a-device-context

There should be a way to call this function from the win32* package. I have searched but could not find it. The closest I could find was this C++ example:

https://cpp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0x9943faca5c529ef258b31b19e70a8cb36341839e74a62560916846e745948643&fullName=wine-master/dlls/gdi32/icm.c&project=r6144/wine

I already tried setting the devmode.ICMMethod and devmode.ICMIntent, and it helped the saturation but not the color matching.